# Arrange numbers 1 to 9 into the upsilon grid

Tags: formation-of-numbers, number-theory

Arrange numbers 1 to 9 into the octagon, so the operation is correct. 
C is a constant.
Do the math operation in sequence, ($×$) and ($/$) is **NOT HIGHER** than ($+$) and ($-$).

[image]

Comment: Do we need to follow BODMAS rule?

Comment: @Techidiot : No (all operation are equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deduce things using the equations.

> As mentioned by @Bojan B (with different notation), we can write down some equations: 
>  `(a - b) * c = C` 
>  `(d * e) / f = C` 
>  `(g - h) + i = C` 
>  `(a + d) / g = C` 
>  `(b + e) / h = C` 
>  `(c * f) - i = C` 
>  
>  Then we can start writing down knowns:
>  1. `a != b != c != d != e != f != g != h != i` 
>  2. `C` is positive, because `(d * e) / f` will not produce less than 1.
>  3. `C` is an integer because `(g - h) + i` will not produce a fraction.
>  4. `a > b`. Otherwise, `(a - b) * c` produces a negative value and contradicts #2. 
>  5. `a != 1`. Otherwise, `b` is not in our set of values. `b != 9`. Otherwise, `a` is not in our set of values.
>  6. If `a + d` is a prime number, then `g` = 1. 
>  7. If `b + e` is a prime number, then `h` = 1. 
>  8. `a + d` and `b + e` both cannot be prime, because both `g` and `h` would be 1. Contradicts #1.
>  9. `g > h` and/or `i > g - h`. Otherwise, `(g - h) + i` produces a negative and contradicts #2.
>  10. `f != 5` and `f != 7` because `d` or `e` would need to be 5 or 7 to satisfy `(d * e) / f` and contradict #1.
>  11. `C < 17` because the largest value of `(g - h) + i` is (9 - 1) + 8 = 16.
>  12. `c * f < 25` because `(c * f) - i = C` or `(c * f) = C + i` and the largest possible value of `C + i` is 16 + 9 = 25 (#11). In order for `cf = 25`, `c = f = 5` (contradicts #1). 
>  13. `c * f` multiplies to 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, or 24 (no multiplies of 5 or 7 because #10).
>  14. `c * f > i`. Otherwise, `(c * f) - i` produces 0 or less.
>  One could keep going with this strategy and (hopefully) eventually deduce a non-brute force solution.

Edit: continuing my efforts.

> Is it possible to add two equations together if we aren't following BODMAS?
>  `(g - h) + i = C`
>  `+ (c * f) - i = C`
>  `= (g - h) + (c * f) = 2C`
>  which would tell us both `g - h` and `c * f` are multiples of `2`. So `g` and `h` are both even or both odd, and from #13, `c * f` no longer multiplies to 3 or 9.
>  Also `c * f > g - h` because `c * f = (g - h) + 2i`.
>  
>  We also have 3 ratios that equal `C`: `(d * e) / f`, `(a + d) / g`, and `(b + e) / h`. Ratios that could potentially satisfy these are:
>  1 = 6/6, 8/8, 9/9
>  2 = 2/1, 4/2, 6/3, 8/4, 12/6, 16/8, 18/9
>  3 = 3/1, 6/2, 9/3, 12/4, 18/6, 24/8
>  4 = 4/1, 8/2, 12/3, 16/4, 24/6
>  6 = 6/1, 12/2, 18/3, 24/4
>  8 = 8/1, 16/2, 24/3
>  I've excluded ones where the numerator can only be factored by the denominator. Since we need 3 unique denominators in a set, I also excluded sets with less than 3 ratios.
>  So we at least know `C` is `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `6` or `8`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this might not be in the spirit of the puzzle, but there was no tag or rule specifying that we can't use computers for this.

So with a help of a computer program that I wrote the only possible solution would be:

> 9 8 2 for the top row, 1 6 3 for the middle row, 5 7 4 for the bottom row, the constant result would be 2 for all 6 equations.

EDIT:

Now that the OP has confirmed that it is ok to use computers, I have written down a short explanation as to how I got the solution. However, it is basically trial-error based, so I hope some one comes up with a more mathematical one (since my math-fu is not strong enough).

Explanation:

> Based on the grid we can extrapolate these 6 equations: 
>  (x1 - x2) * x3 = C; 
>  x4 * x5 / x6 = C; 
>  x7 - x8 + x9 = C; 
>  (x1 + x4) / x7 = C; 
>  (x2 + x5) / x8 = C; 
>  x3 * x6 - x9 = C; 
>  And we know that all equations produce the same result, so:
>  (x1 - x2) * x3 = x4 * x5 / x6 
> and so on. 
>  From here on I just made a program that ran through all permutations of the numbers 1 - 9 as inputs for variables x1,x2,... 
> The algorithm produced the only possible solution to the grid, which is however a purely brute force solution.

Comment: Not sure if its allowed or not, but I got the answer by guessing as well. I was drafting it. But you already have it. +1 This is what I got as well.

Comment: @BojanB Its allowed, but green ticks just for answer with good explanation.