# Arrange (+,-,x,/) into the upsilon grid

Tags: formation-of-numbers, number-theory

- Put operators $(+,-,×,/)$ into the squares.
- Each operator must appears exactly 3 times to make the operations correct.
- C is a constant.
- No BODMA rules ((×) and (/) is **NOT HIGHER** than (+) and (−)), do the math operation in sequence.
- Check [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50712/arrange-numbers-1-to-9-into-the-upsilon-grid) for example.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constant is:

> 6

The final picture is:

> [image]

Comment: Ah you just beat me +1

Comment: Actually, I think this is wrong. You have 4 +s and only 2 xs